# Ruthlessly compressing large images for the web?

Tags: css, image, html, optimization, photoshop

I have a very large background image (about 940x940 pixels) and I'm wondering if anyone has tips for compressing a file this large further than Photoshop can handle? The best compression without serious loss of quality from Photoshop is PNG 8 (250 KB); does anyone know of a way to compress an image down further than this (maybe compress a PNG after it's been saved)?

Comment: Some good info here: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload#CompressImages

Comment: Is it basically a vector?  How big would it be recreated as SVG?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's it's an image of, this will affect how you should compress it?

If it's a photo run it through jpegmini.com, if it's a more icon based PNG is a better choice, and there are many tools to help e.g ImageOptim, pngmini.com, pngquant, (here's some others - http://www.phpied.com/png-optimization-tools/)

if it's vector can you convert it to SVG - this will be a problem for some browsers but you can degrade gracefully.

Finally if it's something like a gradient can you relace it with CSS and degrade for other browsers?

Show us the picture and we can give you better hints